# Why EBNF can't start with {...}

Tags: computer-science, bnf, ebnf

Today, I saw a video on the Youtube. And there are something I couldn't understand.
It says EBNF can't start with `{...}`. Which means this expression:

```
expr => {term + } term;
```

is WRONG. Why?

Comment: Could you please make your question intelligible ? Also, check the [ask] link to make sure your question will get answers by other users.

Comment: Really sorry that it's my first time to use it  : (

Comment: No problem, just take some time to make sure you give as much information as possible to help users understanding your problem and maybe giving you the answers you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your question for better formatting. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for more information on formatting.